# CGSSetWindowWarp and Lion

Tags: osx-lion

I am using the undocument CGSSetWindowWarp function. Unfortunatly, in Lion, it stopped working properly (it works but all mouse events are dropped)
Is someone else encountering teh same issue and have a workaround?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, `CGSSetWindowWarp` is primarily used by the Dock to transform windows which are in the process of being minimized. From this standpoint, disabling mouse events is kind of a feature (since it prevents you from accidentally clicking controls in a rapidly transforming window) -- it's unlikely to be fixed.